# In the Dr. Who episode "The God Complex", could the projection of the weeping angels affect anyone?

Tags: doctor-who, weeping-angels

Some background on this question:

In S05E04, "The Time of Angels", a looped recording of an angel locks eyes with Amy and enters her mind in such a way that she thinks she is turning into stone. Additionally, the following phrase is repeated multiple times:

> That which holds the image of an angel becomes itself an angel.

Fast forward to S06E11, "The God Complex". Gibbis' worst fear are weeping angels, and are clearly manifested in the room with them:

[image: Weeping Angels]

Could these "images of angels" have done harm to anyone had they lingered in the room?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, they could not cause harm in the manner of the Weeping Angels by sending a target to the past. These were not Weeping Angels, nor were their powers being fueled by Weeping Angels.**

In this particular instance they are just what they appeared to be images of Angels created by the technology used to imprison the alien Minotaur. The fear of the Weeping Angels would have been enough to make the person vulnerable to the Minotaur when it came to feed on them. But the Angels in and of themselves would not actually harm them OR be Angels.

**Also see: [Why don't the images in Blink turn into Weeping Angels?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26506/why-dont-the-images-in-blink-turn-into-weeping-angels?rq=1)**

Comment: Fair enough. I suppose these angels had the same power as if someone whipped out a pencil and paper and drew them (which is to say, no power at all).

Comment: On the other hand, if there WERE Weeping Angels about, they WOULD be able to use these representations to activate their power and attack a target. So, there is no truly SAFE image of an Angel to be had. The old monk who wrote the book about them was right...

Answer (score 0):

I think this was a mistake. I don't see what distinguishes an image of an angel on a television screen from that of some nightmare projection. Gibbis' mind is the video tape loop, and the nightmare technology is just accessing that data to play it on the three dimensional television that is the motel. If Gibbis actually saw a real angel, the projection of that image should have the same power. Only explanation I can find is that either Gibbis did not actually see a real angel (heard a vivid campfire story), or the angel whose image is captured must be alive and willing to transfer its consciousness into the image (perhaps it fell into the crack with the others, or said 'screw that crappy motel').